# webkit TextArea with right aligned text doesn't display the space characters

Tags: html, css, webkit

Seems to be affecting webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome, Android, iOS). Works fine with Firefox.

It's easier to show than to explain, please take a look here:

```
<textarea style="text-align:right;"></textarea>
<input type="text" style="text-align:right;"></input>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yP8Aq/2/)

In the TextArea the space character doesn't appear until you type in the next character. For example, try to type "Hello     World" with 5 spaces between "O" and "W", you will notice that spaces do not appear until you type the letter "W". Input field doesn't seems to be having this problem. I wonder if there is a workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
<textarea style="text-align:right; white-space: nowrap;"></textarea>
<input type="text" style="text-align:right; white-space: nowrap;"></input>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yP8Aq/4/)**

Do you need Like This ?

**[NEW JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7gKJT/)**

code is

```
 <textarea style="text-align:right; white-space: normal; wrap:hard;" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I want the text to auto-wrap, which is why I have used the TextArea instead of an input field. Are you aware of any other tricks?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This solution resolvs Chrome and Safari problem, but iOS still has the issue.

Comment: I don't have iOS to test..but you can try <textarea style="text-align:right; white-space: normal; word-break: keep-all;;" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>

Comment: I'm afraid it's having the same issue :( Space appears only when you type in the next character.